# dplyr mutate + unlist issue

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm trying to extract part of character in data frame.

```
d<-data.frame(a=c("aa_bb_cc", "ddd_eee_fff", "sss_rrr_eee"))
```

I'd like to get "bb", "eee", "rrr" part in new column. When use construction like below it works fine:

```
unlist(str_split(d$a[1],"_"))[2]
unlist(str_split(d$a[2],"_"))[2]
```

So I apply it into mutate (dplyr):

```
t<-d %>% mutate(new1=(unlist(str_split(a,"_"))[2]))
```

But the results is "bb" in all cases. What I do wrong?

Comment: The always fun function `word`, i.e. `stringr::word(d$a, 2, sep = '_')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you do

```
d %>% mutate(new1=(unlist(str_split(a,"_"))[2]))
```

it passes `a` column in `str_split`. So this is equivalent of

```
unlist(str_split(d$a, "_"))
#[1] "aa"  "bb"  "cc"  "ddd" "eee" "fff" "sss" "rrr" "eee"
```

and now when you subset it and get the 2nd element it gives

```
unlist(str_split(d$a, "_"))[2]
#[1] "bb"
```

Hence, this value is assigned to all the cases.

---

To resolve this you can add the operation `rowwise` to get your desired output as it will pass the value of `a` for each row separately in `str_split`.

```
library(tidyverse)

d %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(new1= unlist(str_split(a,"_"))[2])

#      a      new1 
#    <fct>    <chr>
#1 aa_bb_cc    bb   
#2 ddd_eee_fff eee  
#3 sss_rrr_eee rrr
```

---

Or another safer option is to use `separate` and divide the string into different columns based on delimiter and `select` the relevant column

```
d %>%
  separate(a, into = c("one", "two", "three"), sep = "_", remove = FALSE) %>%
  select(a, two)

#            a two
#1    aa_bb_cc  bb
#2 ddd_eee_fff eee
#3 sss_rrr_eee rrr
```

---

Obviously you can also use base R option using `sapply` and `strsplit`

```
sapply(strsplit(as.character(d$a), "_"), "[[", 2)
#[1] "bb"  "eee" "rrr"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
d1 <- as.data.frame(unlist(str_split_fixed(d$a,"_", n =3)))
```

Hope this works

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a good excuse to start using (highly customisable) regular expressions:

```
d[["new"]] <- gsub(".*_(.*)_.*", "\\1", d[["a"]])
d
            a new
1    aa_bb_cc  bb
2 ddd_eee_fff eee
3 sss_rrr_eee rrr
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `str_extract`

```
library(tidyverse)
d %>% 
   mutate(new = str_extract(a, "(?<=_)[^_]+"))
#            a new
#1    aa_bb_cc  bb
#2 ddd_eee_fff eee
#3 sss_rrr_eee rrr
```

---

Or with `base R`

```
d$new <- read.table(text = as.character(d$a), header = FALSE, sep="_")[,2]
```